# java array to find the small number

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();

        int[][] numberPair = new int [2][x];

        for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
            for(int k=0; k<2; k++){
                numberPair[k][i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        int[] solution = new int[x];

        for(int i=0; i<x; i++){

            if(numberPair[0][i]<numberPair[1][i]){
                //a minimum
                solution[i] = numberPair[0][i];
            }
            else {
                //b min
                solution[i] = numberPair[1][i];
            }
            for(i=0; i<x; i++)
                System.out.printf(solution[i] + " ");

        }
    }

}
```

Java newb here! This is a basic exercise for choosing the small number between two numbers in a given list and printing them out. It always gives the correct answer for the first one but 0 for the following. I couldn't figure out why, any help or tip will be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: `the small number between two numbers in a given list` ... can you give us an example of what you mean exactly?

Comment: Sample inputs and expected outputs would be helpful.

Comment: For example if first input is 3, then 3 pairs of numbers should be entered and it will print the small numbers in pairs. Let's say:
3
23 34
12 3
14 354
It will print 23 3 14.
I accidentally put last for statement into the previous one, that was what caused the error. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same variable `i` was used for both cycles.
This code will work fine:

```
for(int i=0; i<x; i++){

    if(numberPair[0][i]<numberPair[1][i]){
        //a minimum
        solution[i] = numberPair[0][i];
    }
    else {
        //b min
        solution[i] = numberPair[1][i];
    }
    
}

//this part was inside calculating loop
for(int j=0; j<x; j++)
    System.out.println(solution[i] + " ");
```

Use different variables for different iterations to prevent such errors.

Comment: ```System.out.println(solution[j] + " ");``` Little correction. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your ouput is inside the loop where you fill your array.

Change your code to this:

```
for(int i=0; i<x; i++){

    if(numberPair[0][i]<numberPair[1][i]){
        //a minimum
        solution[i] = numberPair[0][i];
    }
    else {
        //b min
        solution[i] = numberPair[1][i];
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<x; i++) {
    System.out.printf(solution[i] + " ");
}
```